# CalcPay method not working properly

Tags: c#, methods

my CalcPay method is not figuring overtime properly, can anyone see any obvious problems that would cause this?

```
    private const double FED_TAX = 0.2;
    private const int FULL_TIME = 40;
    private const double OVER_TIME = 1.5;
    private const double STATE_TAX = 0.075;


    public double CalcPay()
    {

        double pay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
        double overTimeHors = hoursWorked - FULL_TIME;

        if (overTimeHours > 0)
        {
            pay = overTimeHors * (hourlyWage * OVER_TIME);
        }
        double tax1 = pay * FED_TAX;
        double tax2 = pay * STATE_TAX;
        return ((pay - tax1) - tax2);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample inputs and their expected outputs?

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing clear requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the overtime to the main pay, not replace it:

```
if (overTime > 0)
{
    pay += overTime * (hourlyWage * OVER_TIME);
     // ^ increment
}
```

Comment: If that's not what's wrong, what exactly is wrong? Your method name is misleading. It's shouldn't be CalcPay, it should be CalcOvertimePay

Comment: the method should calc pay if hours < 40 and calc overtime pay if hours > 40

Comment: @BXL There aren't any problems with this solution. What do you mean is not fix?

Comment: this method is part of a larger program that reads data from a file and uses that data to calculate pay. it figures all pay fine unless overtimehours > 40...in which case if figures pay at the normal rate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have redefined the variable pay which means your calculation is based on the overtime rate...